# How to list all SSIS packages on the Sql Server 2008 using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I have no access to connect to the SSIS subsystem via SQL Management Studio, so I was looking for a way to list all the SSIS packages via t-sql. I found [the following query for Sql Server 2005](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSIS-packages-3b247394), but it was not working for 2008:

```
-- List all SSIS packages stored in msdb database. 
SELECT PCK.name AS PackageName 
      ,PCK.[description] AS [Description] 
      ,FLD.foldername AS FolderName 
      ,CASE PCK.packagetype 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Default client' 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'I/O Wizard' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'DTS Designer' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Replication' 
            WHEN 5 THEN 'SSIS Designer' 
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Maintenance Plan' 
            ELSE 'Unknown' END AS PackageTye 
      ,LG.name AS OwnerName 
      ,PCK.isencrypted AS IsEncrypted 
      ,PCK.createdate AS CreateDate 
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10), vermajor) 
       + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(10), verminor) 
       + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(10), verbuild) AS Version 
      ,PCK.vercomments AS VersionComment 
      ,DATALENGTH(PCK.packagedata) AS PackageSize 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90 AS PCK 
     INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysdtspackagefolders90 AS FLD 
         ON PCK.folderid = FLD.folderid 
     INNER JOIN sys.syslogins AS LG 
         ON PCK.ownersid = LG.sid 
ORDER BY PCK.name;
```

After a little bit of research I figured out a query for 2008, so I'd like to share. See the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This query works for Sql Server 2008. The main difference is to use `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages` and use left joins since some packages may have no owner or associated folder.

```
SELECT PCK.name AS PackageName 
      ,PCK.[description] AS [Description] 
      ,FLD.foldername AS FolderName 
      ,CASE PCK.packagetype 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Default client' 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'I/O Wizard' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'DTS Designer' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Replication' 
            WHEN 5 THEN 'SSIS Designer' 
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Maintenance Plan' 
            ELSE 'Unknown' END AS PackageTye 
      ,LG.name AS OwnerName 
      ,PCK.isencrypted AS IsEncrypted 
      ,PCK.createdate AS CreateDate 
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10), vermajor) 
       + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(10), verminor) 
       + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(10), verbuild) AS Version 
      ,PCK.vercomments AS VersionComment 
      ,DATALENGTH(PCK.packagedata) AS PackageSize 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages AS PCK 
     LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders AS FLD 
         ON PCK.folderid = FLD.folderid 
     LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins AS LG 
         ON PCK.ownersid = LG.sid 
ORDER BY PCK.name;
```

Comment: How to get the SSIS Package details (xml) file ?