# is there an way to list the packages in ssis using java

Tags: java, sql-server, ssis, etl

my requirement is to list the packages that are in the ssis using the java, please let me know if you guys have any idea

we can see using the Microsoft studio need those into my application dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where are packages stored in SQL Server?

Referring to [Package Management documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/package-management-ssis-service?view=sql-server-2017):

> The sysssispackages table contains the packages saved to msdb database.

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ and you are deploying databases to the Integration Service catalog, [then the packages are stored in SSISDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh479588(v=sql.110)).

### Connect to SQL Server using Java

You can simply do that by executing an SQL query *(using java.sql)* in Java:

- [Java - JDBC Code Examples for MSSQL](https://www.remwebdevelopment.com/blog/java-jdbc-code-examples-for-mssql-259.html)

### SQL query to list SSIS packages stored in msdb

**msdb version**

You can use a similar query:

```
select * from msdb.dbo.sysssispackages
```

Or you can refer to the following link for an advanced query:

- [How to list all SSIS packages on the Sql Server 2008 using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999312/how-to-list-all-ssis-packages-on-the-sql-server-2008-using-t-sql) *(SQL Server 2005/2008)*

**SSISDB version**

```
SELECT 
    pk.project_id, 
    pj.name 'folder', 
    pk.name, 
    pj.deployed_by_name 'deployed_by' 
FROM
    SSISDB.catalog.packages pk JOIN SSISDB.catalog.projects pj 
    ON (pk.project_id = pj.project_id)
ORDER BY
    folder,
    pk.name
```

- [Script - List all SSIS Packages in SSISDB Catalog](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/List-all-SSIS-packages-in-478d0f4f) *(SQL Server 2012+)*

Comment: thanks it is working for me.. is there any way to see the details of the packages using query..?

Comment: @prasannakumarBala yes there is. Search more on MSDB and SSISDB and you will find a lot of information online